# Angular 5 mat-sidenav

Tags: angular, navigation, angular-material, sidebar

I use Angular v5 with Angular Material. And I have a sidebar for navigation. I have several `mat-list-item` which are shown depending on user roles. Every `mat-list-item` has its own `routerLink`. 
How can I emulate a click on first `mat-list-item` when I show sidebar?

```html
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
        <mat-nav-list>
            <a mat-list-item routerLink="path1" *jhiHasAnyAuthority="['ROLE1']">Item1</a>
            <a mat-list-item routerLink="path2" *jhiHasAnyAuthority="['ROLE2']">Item2</a>
            <a mat-list-item routerLink="path3" *jhiHasAnyAuthority="['ROLE1', 'ROLE3']">Item3</a>
        </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <div>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: Can you show your existing code? What have you tried so far? What exactly is your desired result?

Comment: I have added code expample. So, in <router-outlet> I see data from routerLink path when I click on item. But, I whan to see content of first visible itemt after page is loaded

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear at all.. but i'll try to answer:

you could create a reference to template in mat-list-item like this:

`<mat-list-item #firstItem>...</mat-list-item>`,

then in your component (where you have the toggle/open function) you'll simply call:

```js
@ViewChild('firstItem') fItem: any;

...

openSideBar() {
  this.fItem.click();
}
```